# How to clone a Mac disk in Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mac, ssd, clone

Is there a (preferably free) way I could **clone a Mac disk drive in Windows?**

A friend of mine is considering an upgrade from her old 500GB HDD to a 250GB SSD (Macbook Pro 2011, SATA III present) and I promised to help her.

I think one way would be just to place the SSD in a USB box and use Mac's Disk Utility, but there are two issues with that - the laptop only has USB 2.0 and the SSD is smaller, so I would somehow have to find a **way to resize a live partition**.

My preferred way of doing this would be to place both disks in external boxes, connect them to my laptop and utilize the USB 3 speeds. The problem is, that my laptop runs Windows and **I'm not sure if the process would work without proper filesystem drivers** (APFS and/or HFS+). I found the [Paragon drivers](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/#) for this, but in their free version they only provide read access to the drives AFAIK, so I'm not sure that's the way either.

Thanks for any suggestions and/or experiences.

Comment: You probably should resize (shrink) the partition before anything else, regardless of where and with what you'll be cloning. In Windows there are some free utilities that support the special file system.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i would need an app for mac that does this.
Regarding the window utilities, do you have any particular in mind?

Comment: Software recs are off-topic here.

Comment: I disagree; if you shared the name(s) of the app(s) that support the APFS out of the box in Windows and are free, you'd be answering the question in my very first sentence of the post. I assume that an application that can resize partitions can also clone a disk.

Comment: Not a matter of opinion: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic But I can tell as a comment that Macrium Reflect Free (for Windows) supports Linux and Masc typical file systems.

Comment: Alright, I see now. Thanks for answers and the recommendation.

Comment: Why are you insistent on doing this on Windows? On Mac there are simple, effective & reliable utilities which can do this without worry. No resizing required, so long as the data will actually fit on the new partition; new Recovery partition added too, as part of the process. Speed isn't your worry, effective data transmission/translation is.

Comment: The primary reason was actually the usb 3.0 speed, the other was curiosity - can this actually be done, and if so, would the setup have to be compliacated? If I take into account that the 2011 HDDs' average speed was around 80-90MB/s, and the USB2.0 speed is going to be around 45-50MB/s, it still seems to be worth a try at least.

Comment: So long as the current drive is in fully operable condition & you can get the Mac to stay awake overnight to complete the task, then something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) [there are others, I'm just used to this one] will make a bootable clone + Recovery partition with very little user intervention, from the currently booted OS. There is no need to do this in any recovery-type environment. I would far rather rely on that than some pyramid of HFS/APFS support running on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, that might come in handy.